# Angular 2 global component

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-modules

My structure is as follows :

```
App
    *component, module, template*
    Component 1
        *component, module, template*
        Component 11
            *component, module, template*
    Global Component
        *component, temaplte, BUT NO MODULE*
```

My App module contains the component 1 and component 11 modules. I declared the global component in the app module, so that I can use it in all my other components. I also exported it in app module.

But when I use the selector in the component 11 template, the console says `not a known element`.

I tried importing it in my other components but it says it's already imported, and that I should import it in a higher module.

Could you tell me how to declare a component so that it can be used in child templates ?

Comment: could you post some codes ? at least those module files ..

Comment: Can you check if the module of the App component exports the Global component, and if the module of Component 11 imports the module of the App Component?

Comment: Sorry @5313M, I can't, stack says I have an indent problem in my code, even though I clearly don't have one (my code is 4 spaces indented)

Comment: @Davy the app module exports the component, but the C11 module declares the component. If I import it, it says `unknon directive [Global component]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd assume "global components" are not known in the angular 2 architecture. See also here ==> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html

From experience I know that it can be a problem if components (e.g. pipes) are imported at the app.module level. When doing this with a pipe for example you get a "pipe not found" error. Maybe you encounter a similiar problem with your component.

So I'd recommend to make your component part of a module and then import your module in your app.module instead of the component.

Comment: Sorry for misusing words but it appears clearer for me with that. And the point is that I want my component to be used in several modules, will it be possible if I only import it in a deep module instead of the root module ?

Comment: I think you would be better of if you introduced a "SharedModule" for such global components (as Karl suggested)

Comment: I've used a "toolmodule" for that reason

Comment: Ok so the point is to make a new module that I will use into the other modules ?

Comment: Ok I did it and now I have code errors, but it seems to work. I didn't know that this was the right way to do it. Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to easily use components in different modules is to create a module for your component(s) and `declare` your component(s) in that module and also add them to the `exports` array of the module, then whenever you want to use the component(s), just `import` that module in the module you want to use the component(s).

Comment: You should also remember to export those components in the `exports: []`